# Como pegar todos os dados de uma tabela com base em outra tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela países e outra tabela com continentes que tem como FK o id da tabela países e eu precisava retornar todos os países da Europa. Alguém pode dar uma ajuda de como fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Esta é a estrutura da tabela:

PAISES

id_pais
Pais

CONTINENTES

id_continente
continente
id_pais(FK)

Comment: Tem como editar sua pergunta com a estrutura das tabelas?

Comment: Sem a estrutura da tabela é meio complicado, aproveite e crie um sqlfiddle.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Estava fazendo um sqlfiddle, mas se já conseguiu nem vou terminar

Comment: achei que tinha, mas não. atualizei com minhas tabelas

Comment: Veja o meu SQLFiddle, você terá que mudar suas tabelas.

Answer (score 3):

Depois da edição da pergunta as linhas seguintes ficaram sem sentido.
<s>Quem deve ter uma FK deve ser a tabela de países e não a tabela de continentes.</s>
<s>Um país é que pertence a um continente e não o contrário.</s>

Deve criar as duas tabela da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE continentes (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    ....
    ....
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE paises (
    id INT, 
    continente INT,
    .....
    .....
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (continentes) 
        REFERENCES continentes(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

O SQL para listar os paises do continente id=5 seria algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM paises p
INNER JOIN continentes c ON c.id = p.continente
WHERE c.id = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Sem sua estrutura completa fica difícil de te ajudar. Mas com a informação que destes na pergunta, já dá pra encontrar um erro, você diz

> Tenho uma tabela países e outra tabela **com continentes que tem como FK o id da tabela países**

Isso está errado, está ao contrário. Pense o seguinte, um país tem vários continentes ou um continente tem vários países? Obviamente um continente que tem vários países, logo os países que estão inseridos no continente e não o contrário.

As suas tabelas precisam ficar dessa forma:

```
CONTINENTES         PAISES
---------------------------------------
ID (PK)             ID (PK)
DESCRICAO           DESCRICAO
                    ID_CONTINENTE (FK)
```

E para trazer todos os países de um continente, é necessário fazer um `select` usando `inner join`. Veja mais sobre o `inner join` [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448#6448).

```
SELECT P.DESCRICAO FROM PAISES P
INNER JOIN CONTINENTES C ON C.ID = P.ID_CONTINENTE
WHERE C.ID = 1
```

[Veja funcionando no SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33e04c/1)